# nhibernate named query and icriteria instance

Tags: nhibernate

**Named query and criteria instance**

Can a named query in nhibernate be converted into a criteria instance?

Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no. a named query is an sqlfragment in which you need to set parameter and criteria does not have the API to do so.

Comment: Just a quick point, a named query can be a hql fragment as well which is based on class and property names so it CAN be manually converted.

Comment: @Rippo you are right. Even SQL fragments can be *manually* converted, but then it would be much easier to have a global CriteriaFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Manually yes, automatically no. Not all `HQL` queries can even be manually converted but mostly all can. However said named queries in the `hbm.xml` files have the additional benefit of being parsed and compiled at the time the `SessionFactory` is built, hence given you the additonal benefit of first time run errors. However are a PITA to maintain and refactor.

As a side point I would prefer to upgrade my `HQL` to QueryOver or `LINQ`.

Comment: What have your tried so far? You are asking FAR too much in one go.